# Objective C custom class/view

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I will have about 17 views to create with a custom navigation footer for each containing 3 buttons, each button is customised and not the standard, no wI can do this as I have done with a IB etc but what I would really like to do to learn more etc would be to have a custom class/view that only contains my footer navigation, so then I can then call this in for each view created saving time from doing them in IB.

I have had ago but form an earlier post I am having issues with the dynamically created buttons.  So my question here is whats the best way to create this, via a class or can i create just this in IB and then import to each view/page.

The footer has a prev btn item btn and a next btn, if i can create this so to be able to import then I would pass two vars so that the prev and next buttons know which page they go to.

Any links to creating custom classes / view or help will be much appreciated.

Si

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you've got an assembly of UI objects you are using over and over, making a nib (or xib or whatever they're calling these days) is definitely the way to go.